# parse_resource returned undefined method `ParseResource' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform

I am using parse_resource gem (https://github.com/adelevie/parse_resource) to taking advantage of the infrastructure from Parse.com. I am using Ruby 2.1.1.

After created a model to query the data from Parse. It returned "undefined method `ParseResource' for main:Object". Seems`ParseResource::Base` are not recognised. I couldn't find much on this whether I should include anything in the model or else. Also, I am not sure it is because Rails 4.1 or others.

This is the model looks like;

```
class Venue < ParseResource:Base
fields :name, :address, :phone, :logo, :mini_desc, :website, :email, :more_details

validate_presence_of :name
end
```

As for now, I only would like consume the data from Parse.com which I already done that. Object is privately accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class name syntax is wrong, instead of:

```
class Venue < ParseResource:Base
```

you should write

```
class Venue < ParseResource::Base
```

Comment: Shame on me. Thank you Uri!